# Apply same function to each li element one by one

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-lists, each

I have to create a function for each li in a wordpress page but using the different content of the same attribute that each li has.

This is what I tried to do, I hope it can help you to better understand.

```
jQuery('li.product').each(function() {
   if(window.location.href === "https://www.website.it/shop/"){ 
   var jQueryRightLink = jQuery('a.product-info').attr('href');       
   jQuery('a.add-to-cart-button').attr('href', jQueryRightLink);
   }
});
```

I would copy href of the "a.product-info" element to the "a.add-to-cart-button" element inside each li. Now with what I did all "a.add-to-cart-button" elements get the same href instead of different href.

I tried to search how to repeat the same function separately but with no luck.

Comment: If the product-info and the add-to-cart-button are inside the product, you need to use the `$(<selector>, this)` form, to only select the elements in the product you are iterating over

Comment: Example, `jQuery('a.product-info', this)`

Comment: use `$(this).find("selector")`. *There has to be a dupetarget for this...*

Comment: @Taplar - Just FWIW, there's been talk off and on of deprecating that form. All jQuery does when you use it is literally turn around and do `find(...)` instead. :-)

Comment: Sure it does the find, but it's a difference between one operation and two.  I'm reviewing the source code for confirmation

Comment: @Taplar - That's what I mean: It isn't any more efficient to use that form. The opposite, in fact. (Last I checked was about ~18 months ago.) Not that it matters from an efficiency standpoint either way, it'll be **micro**seconds.

Comment: jQuery object instantiation isn't a small thing.  So to instantiate and then execute a method, which then instantiates another jQuery object for the result, that's two times.  Where as if the $(selector, this) version does not instantiate the first jQuery object, that's a savings

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand if a solution is better than the other.

Comment: `return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );`  meh, looks like it makes a constructor out of the context under the hoods.  So it doesn't really matter after all, :(

Comment: @Luca use which ever you like, with the note from T.J. that the form I suggested has had discussions about potential deprecation.  Other than that, they should both work the same way

Comment: @T.J.Crowder do you have any references to those discussions, by chance?

Comment: @Taplar. Ok, thank you.

Comment: @Taplar - Sorry, just something tickling my memory. Mind you, I'm fairly sure I also recall a fair bit of pushback. :-) *(I was a fly on the wall, not in either camp.)*